# How do I make a jumbotron that scrolls over my background image?

Tags: html, css

I want to make an effect similar to this website http://www.pascalvangemert.nl/ where the background stays static as the user scrolls, and the jumbotron comes up with all the info to cover it. How can I do this? Apologies if this is a noobie question, I'm new to web dev.

[How would I get this skyline to not move and have the jumbotron move to cover it as the user scrolls?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iirTm.jpg)

Thank you

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't exactly a "How Do I Do This?" kind of website. It's a "I've attempted to do this, I've exhausted all research, and now I need to ask you all to help point me in the right direction. This is what I've tried, and it's not working." website. So your question isn't exactly great because this is a well documented problem with hundreds of tutorials, and it's not exactly an "issue" you're having trouble with, you just seem to be looking for a solution to add to your project. Just an FYI in case you get some harsh critics or downvotes.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!